# Trigger href event in .live function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to be able to trigger a typical link event in a .live function, as shown below.

```
$(".next").live('touchstart', function(event) {
   //trigger link event
});
```

Somewhat to the typical a href action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//i assume your href id is 'hrefid'

$(".next").live('touchstart', function(event) {
   //trigger link event
   $("#hrefid").click();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.next').live('touchstart', function(event) {    
 window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to navigate to a page you could do:

```
$(".next").live('touchstart', function(event) {
   //trigger link event
   window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
});
```